# Can't install Pharo on Ubuntu14.10

Tags: ubuntu, pharo

I follow the instruction of this [site](http://pharo.org/download) to install it.
But after update I just get `not found`

> sudo apt-get update
>
> ...
>
> Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pharo/stable/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

So I try to download and run it directly.

> ./pharo

And just get this:

> could not find module vm-display-X11

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
A few weeks later, I can't open the pharo vm any more.
The error message of package manager is:

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    pharo-launcher : Depends: pharo-vm-core-i386 but it is not installable

And the command `apt-get -f install` just want to remove the `pharo-launcher`

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     pharo-launcher
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 52 not upgraded.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the instructions are slightly out of whack. In particular, the latest Ubuntu release they have a stable build for is `trusty`. Maybe change the PPA to point to that instead? Or switch to `unstable`, which does exist for `utopic`.

See https://launchpad.net/~pharo/+archive/ubuntu/stable or https://launchpad.net/~pharo/+archive/ubuntu/unstable (expand the collapsed section for details).

In more detail, what `apt-add-repository` does is simply to add a file called something like `pharo.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` -- just edit this file to suit your needs (of course, you need `sudo` privileges to edit system files). For example, to use the latest stable version, change the file so it contains

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pharo/stable/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pharo/stable/ubuntu trusty main
```

where previously it said `utopic` before `main`.

To finish the change, you need to run `apt-get update` again, which will refresh the Apt databases against your configured sources (i.e. download the `Packages` file from each).

Finally, if this is out of your depth, and you are running Ubuntu just for this, running Trusty instead of Utopic may be the simplest fix; but that entails installing an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Any detailed instruction? I have no idea how to change PPA

Comment: You first link told me to add ppa `pharo/stable` which I already did it and update told me it can't be found. I am totally newbie to `smalltalk` and I think a unstable version may be not suitable for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: There are two files `pharo. ... .list` and `pharo. ... .list.save`. Which one should I edit?

Comment: Because this question has an accepted answer, you'll get better visibility if you post a new question instead.  Maybe rollback your latest edit. Also, this looks like a quite different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386 
 sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
 sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 
 sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:i386
```